# Have an OS toggle on new posts

Tags: feature-request

When talking about video editing, Premiere Pro is a cross platform editing platform (just to name one off the top of my head).

It would be nice to have a toggle or a menu option to say if its running under Windows or Mac. There could be different ways of solving a problem based on what OS its running under (EX formats. Mac likes ProRes, while Windows like AVCHD), and it would prevent the author having to post a comment saying that it does not work/apply on Mac/Windows.

Comment: Perhaps use tags?

Comment: Yea, but that would imply that you can ask questions about the OS in general. Maybe Premiere.windows and Premiere.mac. Where .windows and .mac are subcategories.

Comment: I think using two tags makes more sense, rather than the "subtag".